# RotateAnimation on SeekBar doesn't rotate touch points for thumb

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using a `RotateAnimation` on a `SeekBar` (with `fillAfter` set to true), which visually seems to work fine. The problem is that the touch points for the thumb on the `SeekBar` are still in their old position. So if I rotate the `SeekBar` by 90 degrees, I still have to drag the thumb vertically rather than horizontally. Visually, when I drag a `SeekBar` that has been rotated, the thumb moves in the correct manner even though I'm dragging perpendicular to how it is displayed. This also causes graphical glitches with the thumb.

How do I get the touch points for the `SeekBar` to adhere to the rotation?

Comment: The animation will not change the position of the view, just the visual appearance. So, even though you have rotated the `SeekBar`, it's orientation, in essence, hasn't changed. The only way out is to move the view yourself, once the animation finishes. This is not simple. Are you supporting pre-Honeycomb Android versions? If not, you would want to use `ObjectAnimator` which pretty much takes care of everything.

Comment: @Abhijit Looking at `ObjectAnimator` now. Please move your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation will not change the position of the view, just the visual appearance. So, even though you have rotated the `SeekBar`, it's orientation, in essence, hasn't changed. The only way out is to move the view yourself, once the animation finishes. This is not simple. Are you supporting pre-Honeycomb Android versions? If not, you would want to use `ObjectAnimator` which pretty much takes care of everything.

*Additional references*

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html
- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html
- http://nineoldandroids.com/ (Jake Wharton's library that lets you use Honeycomb animations on prior Android versions)